# How can I specify page numbering for \chapter headers to be in the top right corner?

Tags: fancyhdr, documentclass-writing

I wrote my own Dissertation .cls file and I'm not sure how to make my chapter page numbers located in the top right-hand corner.  I believe the base class is `report` and not `article`.  I was using an example template to begin my work.

Here is the specific part of my .cls file that specifies page numbering location

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%              Specify frontmatter, mainmatter, and backmatter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}\noindent{\bf\uppercase{Chapters}}\hfill\par} % Add the word "Chapters" in the TOC as per University requirements
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % clear the fancy header
    \lhead{} % nothing in the left corner
    \rhead{\thepage} % page number in the top right corner
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % hide the line at the top of the fancy header
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \doublespacing
}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
    \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
    \else
    \clearpage
    \fi
    % \@mainmatterfalse
}
```

I've included the entire .cls file for reference if needed.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%   University of Utah LaTeX Updated Thesis Template
%   Christopher Creveling 
%   12-7-2020
%   Department of Mechanical Engineering
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           Identification
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MastersDoctoralThesis}[12/7/20 MastersDoctoralThesis]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           Report options
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\DeclareOption{11pt}{
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article} % book report
}

%% Execute default options
\ExecuteOptions{11pt}

%% Process given options
\ProcessOptions\relax

%% Load base
\LoadClass[letterpaper]{report}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default

\RequirePackage{setspace} % Single/Doublespacing options
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}% Single spacing in tabular environment

\RequirePackage{subfiles} % Allows for individual components to be created

\RequirePackage{lipsum} % random paragraphs # 66 & 75 are the shortest (4 lines each)
% Required for tables that span multiple pages (used in the symbols, 
% abbreviations and physical constants pages)
\RequirePackage{longtable} 
\RequirePackage{booktabs} % Required for better table rules

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%   Graphicsx package with option to turn on/off images for fast compiling
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % When using ubuntu, this needs to be before tabular
\newbool{graphicDraft} % Option to turn graphics on/off
\DeclareOption{graphicFinal}{\boolfalse{graphicDraft}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%\RequirePackage[draft]{graphicx}
\ifbool{graphicDraft}
    {\RequirePackage[draft]{graphicx}}
    {\RequirePackage[final]{graphicx}}

\RequirePackage{subcaption} % package to create subfigure 
\RequirePackage{animate} % Animating stacks of images (pdf, png, etc.)
\RequirePackage{pdfpages} % Attach PDFs in the document

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                   single spacing for all captions
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage[font=singlespacing]{caption}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           float package
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

% Allows figures and tables to be set in place "[H]"
\RequirePackage{float}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           TodoNotes package
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{todonotes} % to do notes

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                       Geometry of the document
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper          = letterpaper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner          = 1.25in, % Inner margin
    outer          = 1.25in, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset  = 0in, % Binding offset
    top            = 1in, % Top margin
    bottom         = 1in, % Bottom margin
    head           = 2in, % header height % University guideline
    showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                               COLORS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors
\definecolor{BLACK}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{UOFURED}{HTML}{CC0000}
\definecolor{midnightBlue}{HTML}{145680} % midnight blue
\definecolor{darkBrown}{HTML}{654321} % Dark brown
\definecolor{arsenic}{HTML}{3B444B}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                       Chapter heading font size
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{sectsty}

\chapternumberfont{\normalsize} 
\chaptertitlefont{\normalsize}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                               Title spacing
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{titlesec} % Adjust title headers

% Force Heading space after chapter/section/subsection/subsubsections to be the same
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{2em}{2em}[0pt] % two lines of text before and after "2em"
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2em}{2em}[0pt] % two lines of text before and after "2em"
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2em}{2em}[0pt] % two lines of text before and after "2em"
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2em}{2em}[0pt] % two lines of text before and after "2em"

% Single spaced headers
\titleformat{\chapter}      % command
    [display]               % shape
    {\color{UOFURED}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries\doublespacing}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Large\thechapter}
    {0pt}                   % separations
    {\MakeUppercase}        % before
    []              % After (leave blank)

%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\huge\bfseries\singlespacing}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{40pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                               References
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
% `final' to prevent disabling and reference links to be split 
% up on different lines
\RequirePackage[final]{microtype}  


\RequirePackage[defernums=true,
                hyperref,
                backref,
                backend=biber,
                style=ieee,
                natbib=true,
                refsegment=chapter,
                block=space
                ]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend, biber

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} % Spacing between items in bilbiography

% Define typesetting of references heading
\defbibheading{references}[References]{% 
    \section{#1}% Add section so that the table of contents adds the chapter references
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
    \singlespacing
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           Final Bibliography
%   Add type=book, article, online, thesis for specific references
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\def\finalBibliography{
    {\singlespacing
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={\uppercase{Bibliography}}] % Whole
    }
}
    
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                                   Hyperlinks
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=0,
    hypertexnames=true, % reference roman numerals and numeric pages
    colorlinks=true,% Set to false to disable coloring links
    citecolor=darkBrown,% The color of citations
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=UOFURED,% The color of references to document elements (sections, figures, etc)
    urlcolor=midnightBlue,% The color of hyperlinks (URLs) 
    pdfstartview={FitV},
    unicode,
    breaklinks=true, % split up links
}
\RequirePackage{doi} % DOI field in references
\RequirePackage{url} % URL allowed to split up

\RequirePackage[capitalise]{cleveref} % Needs to be loaded after hyperref

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%   % Adjust table of contents, list of figures, list of tables specifically
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft} % Treat the headers as titles
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}   % Puts dots after chapter entries
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\color{UOFURED}\hfill \Large CONTENTS \hfill}  % Normal font
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\color{UOFURED}\hfill \Large LIST OF FIGURES \hfill}  % Normal font
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\color{UOFURED}\hfill \Large LIST OF TABLES \hfill}  % Normal font
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip2pt} % Spacing of the TOC items
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip2pt} % Spacing of the TOC items
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip2pt} % Spacing of the TOC items

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0em} % Force LOT to be the correct width
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0em} % Force LOF to be the correct width

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           Algorithm writing
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{algpseudocode}
\RequirePackage{algorithm}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%                          Thesis Title Page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\def\thesistype#1{\gdef\@thesistype{#1}} % thesis or dissertation
\def\degreeAchieved#1{\gdef\@degreeAchieved{#1}} % exact degree being gotten
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}} % Department
\def\departmentLink#1{\gdef\@departmentLink{#1}} % Department
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}} % Submission date.
\newcommand\skiplines[1]{\vspace{#1\baselineskip}} % function for skipping n number of lines

\newcommand\thesisTitle{
    {
    %\newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}% Doesn't count in table of contents
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
    %\chapter*{\color{BLACK}\uppercase{\@title}} % This doesn't work
        \vspace{1in}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{spacing}{2} % university requirement
                {\doublespacing\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@title}}\\
            \end{spacing}
            \large
            \skiplines{4} % university requirement
            \begin{spacing}{2} % university requirement
                by \\
                \@author \\
            \end{spacing}
            \skiplines{4} % university requirement
            A \@thesistype ~submitted to the faculty of\\
            The University of Utah\\
            in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of \\
            \skiplines{4} % university requirement
            {\@degreeAchieved}\\
            \skiplines{4} % university requirement
            \begin{spacing}{2} % university requirement
                \href{\@departmentLink}{\@department}\\
                \href{http://utah.edu}{The University of Utah}\\ % 
                \@submitdate
            \end{spacing}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
    }
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
% The format of the title page is laid out in elaborate detail.
% Fixes by Nelson Beebe Nov 1992:
% The title is centered in a vbox of fixed height so that it can
% have up to 9 lines.  Version 1.3 and earlier used explicit blank lines,
% which caused spill of the entire titlepage onto a second
% numbered page if a multiline title was specified.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\newlength{\minilength}
\setlength{\minilength}{.95\textwidth}
%
\def\UofUtitlepageNinetyThree{
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \noindent\hspace{1em}%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\minilength}%
        \begin{center}%
            \vbox to 9\baselineskip {%
                \HFmainhead\bfseries
                \vss
                \begin{center}
                    \@title
                \end{center}
                \vss
            }%
            \mbox{} \\
            by\\
            \mbox{} \\
            \@author \\
            \vbox to 15\baselineskip
            {
                \vss
                A \@thesistype ~submitted to the faculty of\\
                The University of Utah\\
                in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of
                \vss
            }
            \@degree \\
            \vskip 7\baselineskip
            \expandafter{\@department}\\
            \mbox{} \\
            The University of Utah \\
            \mbox{} \\
            \@submitdate%
        \end{center}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \ifnoisy \typeout{Title.} \fi
    \newpage% Added 1995 by GBG; see Eric Eide notes.
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%                          Copyright page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} % Copyright year

\newcommand\copyrightpage{
    {\newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}% Doesn't count in table of contents
    %\phantomsection
    %\pdfbookmark{Copyright year}{toc} % Add bookmark to PDF
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
        \begin{center}%
            Copyright \copyright\ \@author\ \@copyrightyear \\
            \skiplines{1} % university requirement
            All Rights Reserved
        \end{center}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage% Added 1995 by GBG; see Eric Eide notes.
    }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%  The committee approval page is highly constrained.  Its format is not
%%  exactly identical to the preprinted ones.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

% Define committee members
\def\committeeChair#1{\gdef\@committeeChair{#1}} % Committee chair #1
\def\advisorTitle#1{\gdef\@\advisorTitle{#1}} % Advisor title (not really used)
\def\committeeMemberII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberII{#1}} % Committee chair #2
\def\committeeMemberIII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIII{#1}} % Committee chair #3
\def\committeeMemberIIII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIII{#1}} % Committee chair #4
\def\committeeMemberIIIII#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIII{#1}} % Committee chair #5

% Define Graduate Dean & Department Chair
\def\graduateDean#1{\gdef\@graduateDean{#1}} % Graduate Dean
\def\departmentChair#1{\gdef\@departmentChair{#1}} % Department Chair
\def\departmentChairTitle#1{\gdef\@departmentChairTitle{#1}} % Department Chair Title
\def\deptmentCollegeSchool#1{\gdef\@deptmentCollegeSchool{#1}} % Department/College/School

% Define approval dates
\def\approvaldepartment#1{\gdef\@approvaldepartment{#1}}
\def\chairDateApproved#1{\gdef\@chairDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIIDateApproved{#1}}
\def\committeeMemberIIIIIDateApproved#1{\gdef\@committeeMemberIIIIIDateApproved{#1}}

\def\bfunderline#1{\underline{\kern 1in \textbf{#1}\kern 1in}}

\RequirePackage{tabularx} % pagewidth tables
\RequirePackage{array} % Specify width of tables
\RequirePackage{ragged2e} % Allows for justification of sections

\long \def \dissertationapproval{%
    \newpage
    %
    \thispagestyle{empty}% Doesn't count in table of contents
    %\phantomsection
    %\pdfbookmark{Dissertation Approval}{toc} % Add bookmark to PDF
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\Large The University of Utah Graduate School} \\
        \skiplines{2} % university requirement
        \textbf{\Large STATEMENT OF DISSERTATION APPROVAL}
        \skiplines{2} % university requirement
    \end{center}
    %
    \justify
    \begin{doublespace}
        The dissertation of\hspace{1in}\bfunderline{\@author} \\
        \skiplines{2} % university requirement
        has been approved by the following supervisory committee members:

        \begin{center}
            \begin{table}[htbp]
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.6\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}}
                    \bfseries{\@committeeChair} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Chair} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@chairDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &   &   \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &   &   \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberIII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &   &   \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                        &   &   \\ % add extra row between the committee members
                    \bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIII} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ , Member} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{\@committeeMemberIIIIIDateApproved}} \\
                    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \tiny{Date Approved} \\
                \end{tabular}%
            \end{table}%
        \end{center}
        
        \justify
        and by \hspace{1in}\bfunderline{\@departmentChair}, {\@departmentChairTitle} of \\
        the {\@deptmentCollegeSchool} of \hspace{1in}\bfunderline{\@approvaldepartment} \\
        and by \bfunderline{\@graduateDean}, Dean of The Graduate School.\\
    \end{doublespace}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%                              Abstract
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\def\abstractString#1{\gdef\@abstractString{#1}} % Abstract

\newcommand\abstractpage{
    {\newpage
    \chapter*{Abstract}
        \setcounter{page}{3} % manually set to page iii
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{Abstract}}
        \hspace{\parindent}
        \begin{doublespace}
            \@abstractString
        \end{doublespace}
    }
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           Dedication page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\def\dedication#1{\gdef\@dedication{#1}} % Dedication

\newcommand\dedicationpage{
    {\newpage       
        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1} % Don't include in page count
        \topskip0pt
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.95\textwidth}%
            \begin{center}%
                \@dedication
            \end{center}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           Frontispiece page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\def\frontispiece#1{\gdef\@frontispiece{#1}} % Frontispiece

\newcommand\frontispiecePage{
    {\newpage       
        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty} % Don't display the page number but still add to the total count
        \topskip0pt
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{{\@frontispiece}}
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%               Epigraph page (Inspirational quote)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\RequirePackage{epigraph} % epigraph package
\def\epigraphQuote#1{\gdef\@epigraphQuote{#1}} % Epigraph quote
\def\epigraphAuthor#1{\gdef\@epigraphAuthor{#1}} % Epigraph author

%\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.6\textwidth} % Width of epigraph

\newcommand\epigraphPage{
    {\newpage       
        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty} % Don't display the page number but still add to the total count
        \topskip0pt
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
            \centering
            \epigraph{\Large{\@epigraphQuote}}{---{\@epigraphAuthor}}
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%              Specify frontmatter, mainmatter, and backmatter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}\noindent{\bf\uppercase{Chapters}}\hfill\par} % Add the word "Chapters" in the TOC as per University requirements
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % clear the fancy header
    \lhead{} % nothing in the left corner
    \rhead{\thepage} % page number in the top right corner
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % hide the line at the top of the fancy header
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \doublespacing
}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
    \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
    \else
    \clearpage
    \fi
    % \@mainmatterfalse
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%                          Custom table of contents
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip5pt\par} % list of figure spacing
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip5pt\par} % list of table spacing

\newcommand\tableOfContents{
    {
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue} % Change color if you want something different
    \clearpage
    \pdfbookmark{Table of Contents}{toc} % Add bookmark to PDF
    \tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents
    
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{List of Figures}} % Adds to TOC
    \listoffigures % Prints the list of figures 
    
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{List of Tables}} % Adds to TOC
    \listoftables % Prints the list of tables
    }
}

% turn off the error for \uppercase in chapter titles
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%            % Mendeley bib file URL issue fix
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps{
        \map{ % Replaces '{\_}', '{_}' or '\_' with just '_'
            \step[fieldsource=url,
                  match=\regexp{\{\\\_\}|\{\_\}|\\\_},
                  replace=\regexp{\_}]
        }
        \map{ % Replaces '{'$\sim$'}', '$\sim$' or '{~}' with just '~'
            \step[fieldsource=url,
                  match=\regexp{\{\$\\sim\$\}|\{\~\}|\$\\sim\$},
                  replace=\regexp{\~}]
        }
        \map{ % Replaces '{\$}'
            \step[fieldsource=url,
                  match=\regexp{\{\\\x{26}\}},
                  replace=\regexp{\x{26}}]
        }
    }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%  % Prevent Orphans and Widows (lines begining at the bottom/top of a page)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}

\endinput
% Christopher Creveling
```

When I define a chapter:

```
\chapter{The first}
```

It adds the page number to the center of the footer.  All other pages are correct when I create new sections and subsections.

First Page
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VUP7.png
Second Page
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8ECx.png

Thanks in advance as I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I guess it's the intention to suppress the fancy header at the beginning of a new chapter page. The contents of the fancy header is irrelevant here and would disturb the clean chapter heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this would be

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I just needed to add that after I defined my pagestyle as fancy.  I read through the documentation afterwards and saw that \chapter redefines the plain style page.  It now works.